# playing sound and changing image in UIImageView when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title describes I've been able to add sound when button is pressed, but I was wondering if there was a way to also add an image change to the main UIImageView when the same button is pressed. Is there any way to stick the picture code in where the "playFaceOfAudioType" method is presented?

Here's my code so far:

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"

@interface FourthViewController ()

@end

@implementation FourthViewController

@synthesize audioPlayer;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)facesAudioAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    [self playFaceAudioOfType:btn.tag];//Tag for button is set on the xib..

}




-(void)playFaceAudioOfType:(int)type{

    [self stopAudio];


    NSString *sound=@"";

    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            sound=@"1";
            break;

        case 2:
            sound=@"2";
            break;

        case 3:
            sound=@"3";
            break;

        case 4:
            sound=@"4";
            break;

        case 5:
            sound=@"5";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:sound
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];



    NSError *error;
    if(url){
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                       initWithContentsOfURL:url
                       error:&error];



        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        }

        [audioPlayer play];
    }


}




-(void)stopAudio{

    if(audioPlayer && [audioPlayer isPlaying]){
        [audioPlayer stop];
        audioPlayer=nil;
    }


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I understand from looking around that usually this is done by doing an if / else if type of approach but was wondering if it was possible to include it along with the switch statement bit.

Comment: Not an Xcode question. Also, that `switch` should be changed to `sound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.mp3", type]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `facesAudioAction` or `playFaceOfAudioType` method for changing image.

Also, you can get rid off switch statement with;

```
NSString *sound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", type];
```

You can set image like this;

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", type];
yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: Ah thanks. How could I code this if I have images named 0.jpg, 1.jpg, etc.?
*Edit*
I set tags on the 5 different buttons, but don't know how to call each of the 5 images based on which button has been pressed.

Comment: Altered my answer accordingly. And your edited question's answer is in your code. You are already getting the sender's tag with type variable. Use it to find which button has been pressed.

Comment: hmm. I get this error. Sorry. I'm still new to iOS. Should I be putting this bit under playFaceAudioOfType?
http://snag.gy/teG63.jpg

Comment: type variable is in playFaceAudioOfType so you should move this to playFaceAudioOfType method. Also you should have an UIImageView to set its image. replace UIImageView.image with your UIImageView's instance name.

Comment: awesome! I got it working, but get this error now: "Unknown class imageView in Interface Builder file." 
I had to do: 
-(void)playFaceAudioOfType:(int)type{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", type];
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

My .h file has:
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

Comment: change weak to strong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33888/discussion-between-steven-p-and-epylepsy)

Answer (score -1):

if you use UIControl's tag, you define `NSString *sound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",type];` in playFaceAudioOfType: function.then you can avoid the switch statement.

And Solution2，you can use `setImage:forState:` method display button's style, and use `button.titleLabel.text` save it's song's information(eg. name).